# total number of those numbers which are less than equal to $x$ and have $n_1$ number of $4$'s and $n_2$ number of $7$'s .

Tags: combinatorics

How do we count the total number of those numbers which are less than equal to $x$ if maximum value of $x$ can be $100000000$ and have $n_1$ number of $4$'s and $n_2$ number of $7$'s.  We are given $n_1$ and $n_2$ and this is to be assumed.

Eg. a number $1234567$ has $n_1=1$ and $n_2=1$.

How do we solve the above problem with the knowledge of combinatorics?

Comment: Pick the locations of the $n_1$ 4's.  From the remaining available pick the locations of the $n_2$ 7's.  From left-to-right pick the value of each remaining digit (can no longer be a $4$ or a $7$).  Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.